# How to embed AOSP Host?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android-automotive

In this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/hmi/aosp_host) there is tutorial how to embed AOSP Host, can somebody read and explain me how and where to do those steps?

Steps done

1.**Check out the code**: I did it

2.**Create the AOSP host APK**: I have AOSPHost.apk ready

3.**Embed the AOSP host**: I do not understand this step, should i do these steps in AOSP repository?

What to do with Android.mk?

```
Add the CarAOSPHost module to your targets as PRODUCT_PACKAGES
```

Where is my target?

```
In your target, add the config file to your targets

PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
<the file root>/com.android.car.templates.host.xml:$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)/etc/permissions/com.android.car.templates.host.xml
```

Where is my target?

What is "the file root"?

What is $(TARGET_COPY_OUT_VENDOR)?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The step 3 is to integrate the APK to the system. Have a look at :https://source.android.com/setup/build/building. You will learn about how to build android system, then you will understand about the step 3.

Comment: @Yong there is note in the end "Note: The permission android.car.permission.TEMPLATE_RENDERER is only available after Android API level 32.". It means I have to build AOSP Android 12+ to integrate this or App should be with minSdk 32?

Comment: I think it means both.

Comment: @Yong thanks. One more question, so i build already AOSP android 12, now I want to embed this APK. I created Android.mk file and pasted what is given in the link above. Now, what to do with this Android.mk file? when i put it inside my android12 aosp project, it gives me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial failed to mention where to put PRODUCT_PACKAGES. After some research, I found out that I should include PRODUCT_PACKAGES to `/AOSP/packages/services/Car/car_product/build/car.mk`.